# Trying to get date using javascript on a laravel Carbon generated date

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, date

I'm using Laravel and setting a columns `timeToEnd` field to a date using `Carbon::now()->addDay(1)` which should give me the next 24 hours. But when I use JavaScript to get the day, hours and secounds from the date generated by carbon it gives me 17 hours.

Here's my code:

```php
$offer->timeToEnd = Carbon::now()->addDay(1);
if ($offer->save()) {
 $isOk = true;
 } else {
 $isOk = false;
}
```

```js
   (function () {
                const second = 1000,
                    minute = second * 60,
                    hour = minute * 60,
                    day = hour * 24;

                let start = v["timeToEnd"], // <- It is the date generated by carbon.
                    countDown = new Date(start).getTime(),
                    interval = setInterval(function () {
                        let now = new Date().getTime(),
                            distance = countDown - now;

                        (document.getElementById(`days${v["id"]}`).innerText =
                            Math.floor(distance / day)),
                            (document.getElementById(
                                `hours${v["id"]}`
                            ).innerText = Math.floor((distance % day) / hour)),
                            (document.getElementById(
                                `minutes${v["id"]}`
                            ).innerText = Math.floor(
                                (distance % hour) / minute
                            )),
                            (document.getElementById(
                                `secounds${v["id"]}`
                            ).innerText = Math.floor(
                                (distance % minute) / second
                            ));

                        if (distance < 0) {
                            (document.getElementById(
                                `days${v["id"]}`
                            ).innerText = 0),
                                (document.getElementById(
                                    `hours${v["id"]}`
                                ).innerText = 0),
                                (document.getElementById(
                                    `minutes${v["id"]}`
                                ).innerText = 0),
                                (document.getElementById(
                                    `secounds${v["id"]}`
                                ).innerText = 0);

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/draw",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {
                                    id: v["id"],
                                    _token: $('meta[name="csrf"]').attr(
                                        "content"
                                    ),
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                },
                                error: function (error) {
                                    console.log(error);
                                },
                            });

                            clearInterval(interval);
                        }
                        //seconds
                    }, 1000);
            })();
```

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: It may be a timezone issue. Try `console.log(v["timeToEnd"])` in your javascript and check your browser's console to see what it contains. From there, you should be able to see why that's happening

Comment: Yes i found out the problem is with carbon it return wrong date probably because of time zone but how do i make it global?

Comment: You can change it to `Carbon::now('UTC')` to set the timezone to UTC

Comment: I did but it does not work. But if i add 30 hours from now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code,

In controller file

```
$time = Carbon::now()->addDay(1);
return view('time', compact('time'));
```

In view file before body tag closed,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var time = '<?php echo $time ?>';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        countDown = new Date(time);
        // console.log(countDown);
        // now you can use your date variable countDown
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm i guess i'm doing that and i realized that the problem is in carbon timezone because from another country it is showing 24hrs but here in my time it shows 17hrs most probably its the issue of timezone.